# MVC Compare email if confirm field is not empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, email-validation

Is there a way to trigger the **Compare Data Annotation** only if the field  **is not empty**?  If not, what is another way to do it?

This code below always trigger the Compare Data Annotation no matter if it has a value or not.

```
[EmailAddress]
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Email Address")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Confirm Email Address")]
[Compare("EmailAddress", ErrorMessage = "The email addresses do not match.")]
public string ConfirmEmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke. Oh okay...I see you already edited the tags.  Gotcha.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easiest to just extend the attribute with your own:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class CompareEnhancedAttribute : CompareAttribute
{
    public bool AllowEmptyStrings { get; set; }

    public CompareEnhancedAttribute(string otherProperty)
        : base(otherProperty)
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (AllowEmptyStrings && string.IsNullOrEmpty(value?.ToString()))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
public sealed class ContactModel
{
    /* omitted other attributes */

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [CompareEnhanced("EmailAddress", AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string ConfirmEmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```